# Reliable way to get exit code from a background process while monitor and kill it when necessary

Tags: bash, process

I came up with a setting that I imagine will do that, except it does not work:

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "Launching a background process that may take hours to finish.."
myprog &
pid=$!
retval=
##At this time pid should hold the process id of myprog
echo "pid=${pid}"

{
    ##check if the process is still running
    psl=$(ps -f -p ${pid} | grep -E "\bmyprog\b")
    killit=
    while [[ ! -z ${psl} ]]
    do
        ##if a file named "kill_flag" is detected, kill the process
        if [[ -e "kill_flag" ]]
        then
            killit=YES
            break
        fi
        #check every 3 seconds
        sleep 3
        psl=$(ps -f -p ${pid} | grep -E "\bmyprog\b")
    done

    ##killit not set, normal exit, read from fd5
    if [[ -z ${killit} ]]
    then
        read <&5 retval
  else
    ##kill here, the wait will return and the sub process ends
    kill ${pid}
  fi

} 5< <( wait ${pid} > /dev/null 2>&1; echo $? )

echo "retval=$retval"
```

At first run it seems all fine, that I can kill the process by `touch kill_flag`, otherwise it waits until the myprog finish normally. But then I noticed I always get the -1 in retval. myprog returns 0 as confirmed by a normal run. Further investigation indicated that the "`echo $?`" part was executed immediately after the script launched, not after the wait command exits. I am wondering what is going on here. I'm pretty new to bash.

Comment: `$pid` is not a child of the subshell that runs the process substitution, you cannot wait for it there.

Comment: Ah that should be it. Based on this I figured out a workable solution as I will post to answer my own question below. 

Thanks @ Stéphane Chazelas !

Answer (score 0):

`wait` can only work on children of the current shell process. The subshell that interprets the code inside `<(...)` cannot wait for a sister process.

The wait would have to be done by the same shell process that started the pid. With `zsh` instead of `bash` (here assuming there's no other background job running):

```
cmd & pid=$!
while (($#jobstates)) {
  [[ -e killfile ]] && kill $pid
  sleep 3
}
wait $pid; echo $?
```

Answer (score 0):

Figured out a workable version:

```
#!/bin/bash
export retval=
##At this time pid should hold the process id of myprog
{
    ##This is the subshell that launched and monitoring myprog
    subsh=$!

    ##Since myprog is probably the only child process of this subsh, it should be pretty safe
    pid=$(ps -f --ppid ${subsh} | grep -E "\bmyprog\b" | gawk '{print $2}' )
    ##check if the process is still running
    psl=$(ps -f -p ${pid} | grep -E "\bmyprog\b")
    killit=
    while [[ ! -z ${psl} ]]
    do
        ##if a file named "kill_flag" is detected, kill the process
        if [[ -e "kill_flag" ]]
        then
            killit=YES
            break
        fi
        #check every 3 seconds
        sleep 3
        psl=$(ps -f -p ${pid} | grep -E "\bmyprog\b")
    done

    ##killit not set, normal exit, read from fd5
    if [[ -z ${killit} ]]
    then
        read <&5 retval
  else
    ##kill here, the wait will return and the sub process ends
    kill ${pid}
  fi

} 5< <( myprog >>logfile 2>&1; echo $? )

echo "retval=$retval"
```

The only annoying thing is that when I kill myprog with a semaphore, an error will raise as the process substitution is dead, but it can be trapped easily.